# R error message unused arguments

Tags: r

I wrote following R code to count the odd numbers:

```
abd<- function (x) {
    k<-0
    for (n in x) {
            if (n%%2==1) k <- k+1
    }
    return k
}
```

But it keep give me unused arguments error whenever i try with string of numbers like abd(c(1,2,3))
Anyone could help?

Comment: `return k` is invalid, and will give you a syntax error before you can even run it, so I'm pretty sure this isn't the **exact** code giving you `unused arguments` errors. Should be `return(k)`. Always post the exact code that is giving the error you report, and cut and paste it back yourself to check. Once I fix `return(k)` it works.

Comment: Also, the whole "count the number of odd numbers" thing can be done in one line without a loop: eg `sum(c(1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5) %%2 )`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just find out that the function only works if you add in the arguments as abd(1:5), but the 'return k' is work the same way as return (k) in this case.

Comment: `return k` does **not work** at all. It cannot possibly work. It is not valid R syntax (unlike Javascript or Python, perhaps).  You **have to** use brackets, as in `return(k)`.

Answer (score 1):

to count the odd numbers, you could do :

```
number <- 1:10
number
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
sum(number %% 2)
#> [1] 5
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, yes, your code is more straight forward, and I just find out that my function only work with multi argument as abd(1:n)